# Putting version file into EAR or WAR using Maven

Tags: java, git, maven, bamboo

My firm is trying to find a way to put some type of version file or versioning on a EAR and or WAR using Maven.

What we need is as we do the Maven Build is to take a version number out of a file and somehow put it into a EAR or WAR or have some better way..

I would like to hear form others on how you do this.

We are using Maven, Git, Bamboo and more. so if somehow Git can put a version or commit number into a file that then Maven can use it would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least to options:

**Customize the manifest entries.**

The war plugin allows you to add some information into the manifest file. Some examples are on the usage page: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html (note: today its ${project.version} and not ${pom.version}.
The ear plugin has options to specify a manifest file or set some environment settings: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/specifying-env-entries-for-the-generated-application-xml.html

**Add the values to a property file and use filters to replace the placeholders.**

Create a simple text or property file in src/main/resources, something like application.properties:

app.version=${project.version}
app.description=${project.description}

and then enable resource filtering: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html for this file.
You can also access environment variables: ${env.variable_name} and using the build number from bamboo (passed as a parameter to the build).

Plugins like the http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/ allow you to also add the SVN revision number or Git Sha1 Commit Hash.

If you are using the release plugin maven adds some information by its own into the maven folder of the released jar or war (inside the meta-inf folder).

Comment: If you're interested in reading such versioning info via web URL too, for instance at `http://example.com/versioninfo.txt` you can filter a `versioninfo.txt` template and [include the version file into the war](http://www.taringamberini.com/en/howto/java/2015/including-release-info-into-war/) by using the `maven-war-plugin`.